# using Jenkins to deploy wcf application to QA, then it references file in Jenkins server

Tags: wcf, jenkins, msbuild, mef

I deployed a WCF application to the qa server using Jenkins.  I got the following error message.

```
        System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
           at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
           at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
           at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InternalGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TryGetExports(ExportProvider provider, ComposablePart part, ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportSubset(PartManager partManager, IEnumerable`1 imports, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart part)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.TryInvoke(Action action)
           at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch batch)
           at IRWebSvc.MEF..ctor() in e:\Jenkins\Jobs\IRWebSvc\workspace\Jenkins__IRWebSvc_dev\IRWebSvc\MEF.cs:line 24
           at IRWebSvc.IRSvc.AddPage(String source, String xmlRequest) in e:\Jenkins\Jobs\IRWebSvc\workspace\Jenkins__IRWebSvc_dev\IRWebSvc\IRSvc.svc.cs:line 30
```

I don't know why it references files in e:\Jenkins\Jobs\IRWebSvc\workspace\Jenkins__IRWebSvc_dev\IRWebSvc folder. This is where I check out the source code from Github.

here's how I compile and  package the application.

```
          <Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="WebConfigTransform">
            <MSBuild Projects="@(SolutionFile)"
                     Targets="Rebuild"
                     Properties="OutDir=%(BuildArtifacts.FullPath);Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(BuildPlatform)" />
          </Target>



          <Target Name="Package" DependsOnTargets="Compile">
            <PropertyGroup>
              <PackageDir>@(BuildArtifacts)\</PackageDir>
              <Source>@(BuildArtifacts)@(Website)</Source>
              <Destination>@(BuildArtifacts)@(PackageFile)</Destination>
            </PropertyGroup>

            <MakeDir Directories="$(PackageDir)" />
            <Exec Command='"@(MsDeploy)" -verb:sync -source:iisApp="$(Source)" -dest:package="$(Destination)"' />
          </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the interface in MEF. all modules using it need to be redeployed. I only deployed the one I need to use. thats why I m getting that error message.